Lower Bound in a sorted array not working as intended
pub fn find_floor(arr: &[i32], target: i32) -> Option<usize> {
    let (mut left, mut right) = (0, arr.len());

    while left < right {
        let mid = (left + right) / 2;

        if arr[mid] > target {
            right = mid;
        } else {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
    }

    if right == 0 {
        None
    } else {
        Some(right - 1)
    }
}

This code work for all test cases other than when the element in the array is repeated.
assert_eq!(find_floor(&[1, 3, 4, 4, 10], 4), Some(2));

Fails
I tried changing the if conditions but in all cases it resulted in the test case failing. An explanation without changing the code will help.
If I fix this test case,
 assert_eq!(find_floor(&[1, 2, 8, 10, 11, 12, 19], 5), Some(1));

fails.
The C++ code that works is
int floor(const std::vector<int> &arr, int target) {
    int left{0}, right{(int) arr.size()}, ans{-1};

    while (left < right) {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;

        if (arr[mid] <= target) {
            ans = mid;
            left = mid + 1;
        } else {
            right = mid;
        }
    }

    return ans;
}


Have you tried stepping through the code?

explanation of why this returns the wrong index in case of repeated elements?

@ChayimFriedman, yes I did try that and I don't know why but the same code in C++ gives the correct answer

@SergioTulentsev yes and any explanation to how the "working" code works?

Not sure what working code you mean. The  C++ code you haven't posted?

@SergioTulentsev sorry for that

The c++ version gives 3 for me on the first example, which means it doesn't work.

I guess I am wrong in 2 languages @trueequalsfalse

After your code finds the target value, the condition arr[mid] > target will never be true (the maximum value it can have is the same as the target, but not a bigger one). This makes it so that left gets bigger with each iteration until the loop stops. Since your code searches from 'right to left' (the right value is the one returned...), it finds the second 4 instead of the first (it finds it first and gets stuck).
You could make your code search from 'left to right' or just add a condition for when this happens.
I'd do something like this:
pub fn find_floor(arr: &[i32], target: i32) -> Option<usize> {
    let (mut left, mut right) = (0, arr.len());

    while left < right {
        let mid = (left + right) / 2;

        if arr[mid] > target {
            right = mid;
        } else if arr[mid] == target {
            return Some(mid); 
        } else {
            left = mid+1;
        }
    }

    None
}


But this doesn't really find the lower_bound/floor, it is just a simple binary search.
